# initializing detail view in swiftUI

Tags: initialization, swiftui

i'm writing a todo list app, and i'm having trouble initializing the detail view.
in HomeView i use a foreach to set up each line.

```
struct HomeListView: View {
    ForEach(items) { item in
        NavigationLink(destination: ItemDetailView(item: item, editMode: true)) {
        ItemView(title: item.title, text: item.text, type: item.type, dueDate: item.dueDate)
    }
}
```

in the ItemDetailView i defined a init() to set up title, text and other properties.

```
struct ItemDetailView: View {
    @State var title: String = ""
    @State var text: String = ""
    @State var type: Int = 0
    @State var dueDate: Date = Date()

    init(item: ItemEntity, editMode: Bool) {
        self.title = item.title
        self.text = item.text
        self.type = item.type
        self.dueDate = item.dueDate
        self.item = item

        print(item.title)
        if self.title.isEmpty {
            print(self.title)
        }

        self.editMode = editMode

        print(self.editMode)
    }
}
```

when i run the app, in the console it prints

```
2

true
4

true
```

i can see that the init() receice the item and set editMode properly, but i can't figure out why the title, text, type and dueDate properties are set to their default values instead of the values in the item that the init receive.

does it have anything to do with the @State wrapper? how can i set their values to what i want?
Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> does it have anything to do with the @State wrapper?

Yes, it does. The state should be initialised via `init` in the next way (example for one)

```swift
struct ItemDetailView: View {
    @State var title: String        // << no, default value
    ...

    init(item: ItemEntity, editMode: Bool) {
        self._title = State<String>(initialValue: item.title) // << explicitly !!
        ...
```